# In Flash CS4 AS3.0 how can I change a shapes fill colour with a click?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fill, cs4

I'm building an activity for young kids where they click on a colour in a palette (mouse cursor will be a paint brush) then click on various shapes that I'll layer to create a picture.

depending on the colour they select they should be able to fill the shapes with that colour. Change colors half way through change their mind etc.

I have no issues using an earlier AS version if its easier.

Comment: Seems like you have the beginnings of an idea here, but you will need to create a more detailed plan of exactly how you want your program to work before you can build it, or even get more constructive help. --- "Change colors half way through change their mind etc." is the confusing point, how exactly would you want this to work.

Comment: actually, that was dumb of me to suggest using Tweener.  i've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html) - there are examples in the linked documentation.

it's also very easy to do this using [Tweener's ColorShortcuts](http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/) by assigning the `_Color` property a hexidecimal color value.  this method additionally lets you very easily fade in the color by optionally assigning a non-zero value to the required `time` property.

```
Tweener.addTween(myShape, {time: 0.0, _Color: 0xFF0000});
```

keep in mind that any bitmap filters, like drop shadows, or any children of your shape (if it's a sprite) will also change color.  although it's just as easy to separate each element of your shape by using a container.

---

**[EDIT]** rather than using Tweener, as i hastily suggested earlier, or the rather complicated ColorMatrixFilter, you can use a [ColorTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html) object to easily change the color of a display object.  this is also the most common approach in AS3.  here's an example:

```
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

var myShape:Shape = new Shape();
myShape.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
myShape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
myShape.graphics.endFill();

addChild(myShape);

var myColorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform;
myColorTransform.color = 0x0000FF;
myShape.transform.colorTransform = myColorTransform;
```

the above code draws a red rect, adds it to the stage and then uses a ColorTransform object to change its color to blue.

Answer (score 0):

I must warn you that getting this to work the same way that say Paint works will be actually pretty difficult.

I'd look at making your entire canvas a `Bitmap`.

Resources:

1. [`Bitmap`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html)
2. [`BitmapData`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) (this one will have the key methods)

When shapes are drawn and whatnot, use the [`fillRect()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#fillRect%28%29) method. For a tool like a paint bucket (like in paint), take a look at the [`floodFill()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#floodFill%28%29) method.

I'm not really sure how could could create a paint bucket tool, but my mind is thinking along the lines of having a loop that uses [`getPixel()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel%28%29) to check out the colours of each of the pixels surrounding where you click, and then uses [`setPixel()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#setPixel%28%29) to change the colour of each. You'll have to create a method that returns an array of all the pixels that are of a certain colour and not blocked off by another colour (ie so you don't use the paint bucket and change the colour of **all** the pixels on the canvas).

There's likely libraries out there for this sort of stuff too.

Hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: this will work, but it's possibly the most difficult solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or just use a filter. See `DisplayObject.filters`

Comment: By breaking down the shapes into parts, which can be 'filled' by applying a colour filter.

Comment: I'm interested, could you provide an example?

Comment: apply colour filter to shape => shape turns to that colour (in its entirety: nothing clever) hth.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was thinking that all the shapes would be merged into a bitmap (so not separate). If this isn't the case you could use colorTransform.